# Ordinal category theory?

Tags: higher-category-theory, ordinal-numbers

Just out of curiosity: Is there a notion of $\alpha$-category for an ordinal number $\alpha$, extending the given notions for $\alpha \leq \omega$? If there is none, which one would you propose? Feel free to draw images.

Comment: One can also dream of a notion of x-category for any real (or whatever) number x. 

Comment: I imagine that the difficulty would be in what you must do for limit ordinals.

Comment: Here is an idea: giving a higher category is equivalent so giving its nerve, which is a simplicial that satisfies some horn filling condition.
Now one could define $\alpha$-categories by taking "huge simplical sets" which are indexed not only by the finite ordinals but by ordinals smaller than $\alpha$ and again impose some horn filling condition.

Comment: @Jan: I don't think that would work. That would give you a notion of an $(\alpha,1)$-category.  The simplicial models of Verity and Street for (even strict) higher categories with noninvertible higher cells make use of thin cells, which are "marked" cells in a stratified simplicial set.  

Comment: This question seems similar to the question I asked here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/91213/how-would-generalizing-simplicial-sets-affect-infty-1-functors-between-in

Comment: I have asked a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928708

Answer (score 7):

Let $\Delta_2$ the 2-tronked simplicial category (objects are the finite orders $0=$(0), $1=$(0,1),  $2=$(0, 1, 2) and order-preserving functions). Then $Cat$ (category of small categories)is isomorphically  to $Fun_c(\Delta_2^{op}, Set)$ (finite limits preserving functors and natural transformations).
More in general the (hyper)category of n-double small categories $n$-$Double$   is isomorphically  to $Fun_c((\Delta_2^{op}\times\ldots\times\Delta_2^{op}), Set)$ (n fold products), and  $n$-$Cat$ is a subcategory of $n$-$Double$ (elements of $Fun_c((\Delta_2^{op}\times\ldots\times\Delta_2^{op}), Set)$ that send some morphisms to identities). Of course you can generalize this for a infinite cardinal  $n$.

Comment: Thanks! Can you give a reference for the isomorphism $\mathrm{Cat} \cong \mathrm{Fun}_c(\Delta^{\mathrm{op}},\mathrm{Set})$? The functor is probably the nerve, which is fully faithful, but I haven't come across this description of the image.

Comment: Its a old folklore property,  for example P.Johnstone "Topos theory" p.48, remark. 2.13. That double categories are Cat-object (internal categories) inside Cat (this last is the category of Cat object come from  JW Gray, Formal category theory Lnm 391, or R. Brown article "Double categorie, 2.categories, thin-structures, connections" (is mentioned as a result, no more hard than  a nice exercise).


Comment: 
YOu can find a more simple algebraic description of $\omega$-category (stright generalizable to infinite cardinals) in R. Street "The algebra of oriented simplexes" J. Pure Appl. Alg.49 (http://www.math.mq.edu.au/~street/aos.pdf) 