# How would generalizing simplicial sets affect $(\infty,1)$-functors between $(\infty,1)$-categories?

Tags: ct.category-theory

The simplex category $\Delta$ is defined as the category of (non-empty) finite ordinals and order preserving maps. Furthermore, a simplicial set $X$ is defined as a contravariant functor $X: \Delta \rightarrow \text{Set}$.

I am interested in the possibility of generalizing the notion of a simplicial set by considering the category of infinite ordinals $\mathcal{O}$, if such a thing exists, and then defining an $\infty$-simplicial set as $X^{\infty}: \mathcal{O} \rightarrow \text{Set*}$, where $\text{Set*}$ is the appropriate adjustment of the category of small sets $\text{Set}$ such that mapping from objects in the category of infinite ordinals will still satisfy contravariance.

Assuming such a generalization exists, how does this affect the geometric definition of an $(\infty,1)$-category? Is there no longer a capturing of the geometric model desired from simplicial sets or can something more general than an $(\infty,1)$-category be defined? It would also be interesting to see how this would change $(\infty,1)$-functors between simplicial to sets to some other type of functor between $X^{\infty}$ sets. What would natural transformations look like, if they could still be defined properly?

EDIT: I asked this question to a graduate student who is doing work in $\infty$-categories, and he said that you would not get the same geometric model you want by quasicategories if you allowed infinite ordinals. Does this make sense to anyone? He said, that by taking the geometric realization "you probably wouldn't get anything back", but I don't really know what to make of that.

EDIT 2: This question has really been interesting me, and I can't find anything on it in Lurie's Higher Topos Theory or any other literature I have looked through. It seems like any time an author introduces the idea of a simplicial set to aid in defining quasicategories they don't think about possible variations on the simplex category that might change the entire construction they are making into something completely different. Let me know if you want a more specific question to answer!

Comment: I've asked a very similar question here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/75610/

Comment: One refinement: the simplex category is *not* usually defined as the category of finite ordinals.  Although usage varies, it is far more frequently the category of *nonempty* finite ordinals. 

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: It looks your question didn't get any real answers, have you found anything in your studies since to suggest that something can be defined, or found any related research on the topic? There's so work done on higher category theory that I doubt someone has not tried to work on this!

@TomLeinster: Fixed, thank you for the suggestion!

Comment: You could also restrict to the category of nonempty _countable_ ordinals. If you take _all_ ordinals, size considerations become even more important than they already are when dealing with simplicial sets and (oo,1)-categories.

Comment: @DavidRoberts: So, if I do restrict $X^{\infty}$ to be all countable ordinals do you know what might happen, or if there has been any research on this or should I just set aside a week and try to figure this out?

Comment: No idea! I think there was something once about defining infinity categories as a set with operations, in a way which included infinity-arrows, but it was an isolated observation. The big question is why?

Comment: Maybe I'm being dense, but is there any reason to ask this question? It sounds to me like saying "I'm tired of multiplying only finitely many elements in a group, can I have a structure that's like a group but lets me multiply an _arbitrary ordinal_'s worth of elements together?". Would you mind sharing some reasons you think this might be of some interest? (I doubt you'll get many answers unless you do.)

Comment: I have asked a similar question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/928708

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena: a class of morphisms in a category is *cellular* if (among other properties) it is closed under transfinite composition. What is "transfinite composition" of edges in a $\infty$-category? Sure, you have a naive idea of it being the colimit of a diagram; but does this coincide with a more attentive notion of "composition" as "(non-unique, non-operational) solution to a lifting problem"? I could be a grain of salt in a tank of water, but all my current interests revolve around the calculus of orthogonal classes in $\infty$-categories, together w/ closure properties thereof

Comment: @OmarAntolín-Camarena to mention another application, a notion of "transfinite composition" of edges is the necessary tool to study the Small Object Argument in $\infty$-categorical factorization systems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems to me that there should be some not too nebulous
motivation for such a question.  Rather than answer the
question as stated, I'll give an open problem along the 
same lines.  It starts with an old and much neglected paper:
Daniel M. Kan
Semisimplicial spectra
Illinois J. Math. Volume 7 (1963), 463-478.
That gives an analogue of based simplicial sets that allows
for simplices of negative dimension and is designed to give
an alternative definition of spectra.  There are problems 
with the smash product and there are several later papers that 
flesh out the theory (Kan and Whitehead, Burghelea and coauthors).
I would be curious to see how this definition fits into the modern 
world of spectra.  There is a notion of Kan semisimplicial spectrum
(opus cit) and it seems very natural to wonder if there is an
interesting version of stable quasicategories sitting as a 
subcategory of the category of Kan semisimplicial spectra.